# Jenkins Spock Tests failing with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-spock

`JenkinsPipelineSpecification` based tests fail with the error: *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the tests ran in Maven, but failed with the above error in IntelliJ IDEA. I fixed it by setting the project SDK and language level to 1.8 under File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK / Project language level.
Maybe that helps someone out there.